# How to use bind variables for date literals?

Tags: sql, oracle

Consider the following SQL

```
SELECT * FROM employee WHERE dob = DATE '1980-05-15'
```

I need to rewrite the query to get rid of the hard coded values and use bind variables instead. So, my rewritten query looks like this

```
SELECT * FROM employee WHERE dob = DATE :dateOfBirth
```

However, the query doesn't work. I've tried all possible formats (1980-05-15, 15-MAY-80, 15-MAY-1980) for :dateOfBirth variable, without any luck. I always get *ORA-00936: missing expression* error.

**Note 1:** I'm aware of to_date() function that can solve my issue, but I can't use that because the query originates from a different system on which I don't have any control over.

**Note 2:** DD-MON-RR is the nls_date_format in my database as specified in nls_session_parameters & nls_database_parameters

Comment: Where do you want to run the query ? and if you say you cannot use `to_date` as it is generated from some other system , then how do you introduce the bind variable then ? i am not clear on this. could you clarify ?

Comment: My application receives the original query from another system (a product that is no longer supported). I parse this query in the Java / Spring middleware and convert it to use bind variables instead. The converted query is then executed against Oracle from my middleware.

But this problem exists irrespective of I execute the query from my middleware or if I directly execute on SQL Developer.

Comment: Can you define the bind as an Oracle `date` and then just use `where dob = :dateOfBirth`? Does it have to be a string requiring conversion by the database?

Answer (score 2):

You can't, you need to `to_date` it:

```
SELECT * FROM employee WHERE dob = to_date ( :dateOfBirth, '<fmt>' );
```